# DefaultIfEmpty in LINQ-to-SQL join causing duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is an extract of my query:

```
...
join p in dc.PODs on c.ID equals p.Consignment into pg
from pgg in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()
...
```

What the query should do is get all the 'PODs' associated with a consignment, store it as an IEnumerable object (which seems to work) so I can run through it when querying the main IEnumerable generated from the query.

The problem is, I am getting duplicate main rows with the DefaultIfEmpty line, which only happens when a row has multiple PODs - so it's returning a row for each POD, which is incorrect. If I take out the pg.DefaultIfEmpty() line, it *seems* to work a bit better, but I still want to get the rows without PODs.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Sorry, at the moment I cant' as I work on a machine with no Internet access. When I have 5 minutes I'll type it up :)

Comment: Work with no internet access? Wouldn't manage a second

Comment: Neither would I! We develop remotely on the customers server at the moment, and I have another PC next to it for Internet/email

Comment: wait, you're developing on the customers server. oh boy

Comment: A quick comment. You can use `p` again after the `into`. so you can write it as `from p in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()` to make the query easier to follow IMO. Not sure about the actual answer, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgive me if I'm off on your intention because I can't see the complete structure of your data or your initial `from` or final `select` clause in your query excerpt.  So I'm posting what I think is a solution based on your snippet and sample data I constructed.  Let me know if I'm off and I'll correct it.

If you want a list of rows of consignments to PODs, with each consignment to POD on its own line, you could do something like this (keep in mind my `from` and `select` clause are based on my sample data):

```
        // select the consignment id & name (i made up) and each matching POD
        var results = from c in consignments
                      join p in dc.PODs on c.ID equals p.Consignment into pg
                      from pgg in pg.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, POD = pgg };

        // This is just a SAMPLE display just for kicks and grins
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name + " " + ((r.POD != null)
                                                ? (r.POD.Consignment + " " + r.POD.Description)
                                                : "none"));
        }
```

This query outputs something like:

```
One 1 TextBox
Two none
Three 3 Refridgerator
Three 3 Bucket
Four none
Five none
```

However I'm not quite sure I understand your remark:

> "The problem is, I am getting
>   duplicate main rows"

I'm not sure if you're saying you don't want to see the one consignment per purchase per row where each result in the `IEnumerable` is an item with the consignment and a sequence of PODs, you'd want a query like:

```
        // select the Consignment ID and Name (i made up), and list of PODs
        // instead of the individual POD
        var results = from c in consignments
                      join p in dc.PODs on c.ID equals p.Consignment into pg
                      select new { ID = c.ID, Name = c.Name, PODs = pg };

        // This is just a SAMPLE display just for kicks and grins
        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r.Name + " ");

            if (r.PODs.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var pod in r.PODs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + pod.Consignment + " " + pod.Description);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tNone");
            }
        }
```

Where the select is selecting the POD list instead of the individual match, which outputs like this:

```
  One
        1 TextBox
  Two
        None
  Three
        3 Refridgerator
        3 Bucket
  Four
        None
  Five
        None
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to confirm for your 2nd case, wouldn't the output be without the Two, Four, Five which have none item since it is not an outer join? 
`One
        1 TextBox
  Three
        3 Refridgerator
        3 Bucket`

What I tried was use an equivalent WHERE IN for dc.PODS. 
`....join appraisal in ef_appraisal on application.a_appraisalid equals appraisal.a_appraisalid

                        where

                            (from r in ..

                             select r.r_applicationid).Contains(application.a_id)  )`

Do share if you have other ideas